# Why does this Microdata not validate in the Google tool?

Tags: html, microdata, google-rich-snippets-tool

The `name` property (in the `meta` tag) is not recognised in the Google Webmasters validation tool. Why is this?

```html
  <table itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="An idea suitable for potential candidate for the fourth plinth" />
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Suitable for</td><td>potential candidate for the fourth plinth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      <td class="label">Price</td><td itemprop="price">£1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Notes</td><td>None</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? The name markup is for a product name, You don't want to display the name, is that why you're trying to use "content"?

Comment: Its silly to have a td element that is blank with meta information. You shouldn't need the TD element at all if you don't plan to display no information.

Comment: @guisasso The product name spans two `td` cells and also depends somewhat on page context i.e. the page sells 'ideas' (weird I know but it is an art project) so repeating 'An idea ' inside every product table looks redundant from a style point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because the product name is not visible, it is placed incorrectly in a table structure.

A simple change to:

```
<table itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

<tr>
  <td class="label">
   <meta itemprop="name" content="An idea suitable for potential candidate for the fourth plinth" />Suitable for
  </td>
  <td>potential candidate for the fourth plinth
  </td>
</tr>
<tr itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <td class="label">Price</td><td itemprop="price">£1000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="label">Notes</td><td>None</td>
</tr>
```

Will make it work.